# How to make this button behavior using pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to make this button have this behavior.

- Clicked
- Disabled the button
- Do something
- Enabled the button
- Alert success text.

The script should be **inline**. This is my current button script.

```
<button type="button" onclick="this.disabled=true;savemain();this.disabled=false" class="btn btn-success">Simpan</button>
```

Comment: note, if "Do something" is asynchronous, then your inline script will enable the button before the asynchronous code completes - that may or may not be an issue for you.

Comment: You need to rethink your code. `savemain` will be asynchronous, therefore the button will be enabled too soon. if `savemain` has an error (which sounds like the case from your comment in the answer below) the button may not be enabled at all - check your developer tools console for errors

Comment: It's solved. I use `document.getElementById('btn_simpan').disabled = false;`  in AJAX success not only `this.disabled = false;`.

Comment: Thanks for all your clues and suggestions

Comment: `not only this.disabled = false;` - you should totally remove `this.disabled=false`

Comment: yeah I change `this.disabled = false;` to `document.getElementById('btn_simpan').disabled = false;` to enable it. The button disabled script is still inline though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using inline javascript

```
<button type="button" onclick="this.disabled=true;savemain();this.disabled=false;alert('success');" class="btn btn-success">Simpan</button>
```

```js
function savemain(){
 console.log('doing stuff');
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="this.disabled=true;savemain();this.disabled=false;alert('success');" class="btn btn-success">Simpan</button>
```

Or use an addEventListener instead and it should do the trick.

```
document.getElementById('buttonId').addEventListener('click', function(event){
  this.disabled = true;
  savemain();
  this.disabled = false;
  alert('success');
}, false);
```

I don't really suggest using inline JavaScript.

Comment: How to make it inline inside the button ?

Comment: add the `alert('success');` to your inline code - seems obvious

Comment: @Shota, just updated my answer. Can you tell us why it has to be inline Javascript?

Comment: clearly it doesn't need to be all inline, since there's a call to a function called `savemain` - why the enable/disable logic isn't moved there is a mystery

Comment: the button is not enabled after the function. why?

Comment: @kevlai22 When I put the disabled/enabled inline the button, the button is disabled but not enabled after the script. And if I put the disabled/enabled  in savemain(), the button is not disabled/enabled at all

Comment: @Shota I can't really tell, but I have just put a snippet in my answer so you can play it around to see what went wrong. Can you tell us how you do the disable/enable thing in savemain()? Or tell us generally what savemain() does?

Comment: savemain() is AJAX script to post a form. My problem is solved now, thanks.

Comment: @Shota Good to know! And accept my answer please and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is considered bad practice. It's better to use traditional DOM event handlers or DOM Level 2 Event Listeners.